# Prototype inheritance: Calling super constructor in sub "class" constructor function

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I am trying to understand this piece of code and am wondering why we have a call to super constructor function in the sub "class" constructor function:

```
function Person(name) {
   this.name = name;
}
// Other properties on Person prototype here...

function Employee(id, name) {
    Person.call(this, name);   // Why do we have to do this?
    this.id = id;
}
Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
// Other properties on Employee prototype here...
```

1) Why do we have `Person.call(this, name)` ? In "Secrets of the Javascript Ninja", they do `prototype` inheritance **WITHOUT** calling the super constructor (the rest of the code is the same, except `Object.create` , but I understand why that is needed).

Comment: I think in a classic inheritance scenario, you will say `base(name)` when `name` of an person is to be set thru Employee `ctor` (assuming base class has `ctor` taking name as string). Same is achieved here with prototype inheritance...

Comment: It re uses Person constructor code and makes instance specific members of Person instance specific members of the to be created Employee. Funny that the book you mentioned doesn't do that. Maybe this answer can show why you should do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is the prototype chain of your Employee (and Person) without the line `Person.call(this,name)`:

```
|Person|                       |Employee|
|------|                       |--------|
|name  |                       |wage    |
|sex   |                       |id      |

   |                               |
   |                               |
   v                               v

|Person Prototype|             |Employee Prototype|
|----------------|             |------------------|
|walk()          |  <--------  |work()            |
|eat()           |             |goOnStrike()      |
|sleep()         |

   |
   |
   v

|Object|
|------|
| ***  |
```

Every time, you request a property of an employee, JavaScript looks for that property by traveling down the prototype chain. If you write this:

```
var employee = new Employee(1, "Jack White");
employee.walk();
```

JavaScript will look in `employee`, than in `employee.[[prototype]]` and then in `employee.[[prototype]].[[prototype]]` (following the arrow directions in the diagram) until it finds the property `walk`.

As you can see, if you request the property `name`, JavaScript will not find it, because it is not in the prototype chain of `employee`. So you have to make sure, to also "copy" local properties like `name` and `sex`.

You do this by calling the constructor of `Person` with the context of the current `Employee`:

```
function Employee(id, name) {
    Person.call(this, name);
    this.id = id;
}
```

which does essentially the same as if you would just copy all the code from inside of the Person constructor in the Employee constructor:

```
function Employee(id, name) {
    this.name = name; //copied from Person
    this.id = id;
}
```

This results in the following setup and an employee with a name property:

```
|Person|                       |Employee|
|------|                       |--------|
|name  |                       |wage    |
|sex   |                       |id      |
                               |name    |
                               |sex     |

   |                               |
   |                               |
   v                               v

|Person Prototype|             |Employee Prototype|
|----------------|             |------------------|
|walk()          |  <--------  |work()            |
|eat()           |             |goOnStrike()      |
|sleep()         |

   |
   |
   v

|Object|
|------|
| ***  |
```

Comment: Very detailed answer. Although Joe's answer is sufficient, I believe this is a better explanation for people new to JS inheritance.

Comment: I'd agree.  That's a heck of an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not calling the super's constructor implies that the subclass has some knowledge of the superclass's behavior: that's the opposite of encapsulation. It shouldn't know if the parent class needs or doesn't need any kind of 'setup' in its constructor. To be safe, it should simply call it and carry on.

For example, if Person always had to initialize a bunch of properties on instantiation, and Employee *didn't* call Person constructor, Employee instance operations that rely on Person properties/methods may not behave properly.